Why does the Japanese blurb for The Lightning Thief say that it's a mystery novel?
I'm reading a Japanese translation of Percy Jackson and the Olympians: The Lightning Thief, by Rick Riordan, translated as 「パーシー・ジャクソンとオリンポスの神々　盗まれた雷撃」by 金原瑞人 (Mizuhito Kanehara). The marketing copy on the inside flap is very insistent that it's a mystery novel.

アメリカ探偵作家クラブ賞受賞の実力派ミステリー作家によるギリシャ神話とミステリの融合。スピーディな展開、二転三転する犯人……、新感覚ミステリ・ファンタジーシリーズ第一弾！

My translation (bolding mine, and please pardon my bad Japanese)

A blend of Greek myth and mystery by a talented mystery author and Mystery Writers of America award recipient. A fast-paced plot, a few twists for the culprit… the first in a new mystery/fantasy series!

Riordan did win an Edgar Award from the Mystery Writers of America, but for a completely different book called The Widower's Two-Step. And I would not call The Lightning Thief a mystery. It's more properly a fantasy adventure. The English blurbs that I've seen (e.g. Goodreads, Amazon) don't mention it being a mystery.
Technically there are twists that reveal an antagonist, but that's not what the plot is focused around. Once the book gets going properly (i.e. after the exposition and set-up at Camp Half-Blood), it's a travel adventure to the Underworld. The protagonists are more focused on going there and back (without dying) than investigating.
Given that, why is this book marketed as a mystery to the Japanese audience?

It's a mystery to me.

The Japanese Wikipedia article for ミステリ offers little elucidation: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ミステリ
